# How to pass variable from app.js to routes/index.js?

Tags: node.js, express, shrinkroute

I'm using shrinkroute https://npmjs.org/package/shrinkroute to make links in nodejs. I get error 500 ReferenceError: shrinkr is not defined

How to pass shrinkroute to routes/index.js? Is there a better way to create url by passing query string args?

```
//app.js
var app = express();

var shrinkr = shrinkroute( app, {
    "user": {
        path: "/user/:id?",
        get: routes.showOrListUsers
    }
});
//url method works in app.js    
var url = shrinkr.url( "user", { id: 5, page:40, type:'a' } );
console.log(url);

app.use( shrinkr.middleware );

//routes/index.js
exports.showOrListUsers = function(req, res, next) {                       
    console.log(req.params); 
    //shrinkr errors out in index.js                                      
    var url2 = shrinkr.url( "users", {name: "foo"});                       
    console.log(url2);                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One solution would be to store `shrinkr` in your app object using [`app.set`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set):

```
// app.js
...
app.set('shrinkr', shrinkr);
...
```

In `routes/index.js`, you can access it through the `req.app` or `res.app` objects:

```
exports.showOrListUsers = function(req, res, next) {
  var shrinkr = req.app.get('shrinkr');
  ...
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more idiomatic to use [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals) to set app local variables?

Comment: @YanFoto yeah that's another option. One (slight) drawback of using `app.locals` is that it gets exposed to templates.

Comment: What if you have a lot of handlers in `routes/index.js`? you will have to duplicate `var shrinkr = req.app.get('shrinkr');` in each function?

Comment: @Avishay28 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20790676/893780), specifically _"Using the middleware"_

Answer (score 12):

A bit late to the party, but the following works as well:

**app.js**

```js
var my_var = 'your variable';

var route = require('./routes/index')(my_var);
app.get('/', route);
```

and meanwhile in **route.js**

```js
var express = require('express')
,   router = express.Router()

// Router functions here, as normal; each of these
// run only on requests to the server

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).end('Howdy');
});


module.exports = function(my_var){

    // do as you wish
    // this runs in background, not on each
    // request

    return router;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me out!

Comment: I was hoping this would work for me, but no luck so far. Can you elaborate on this answer, focusing I suppose on how the variable gets passed? Scope issues? Situations where this should work? Or perhaps won't work? Thanks.

Comment: This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Two easy ways to achieve what you want:

## 1. Accessing your shrinkroute instance from within your route

Simple as that. Nothing else is required after Shrinkroute is setup.

```
exports.showOrListUsers = function(req, res, next) {
  var shrinkr = req.app.shrinkroute;
  console.log( "Route: " + req.route.name ); // ta-da, made available by Shrinkroute
  // do your URL buildings
};
```

## 2. Using the middleware

If you don't want be tempted with non URL building methods of Shrinkroute, you can use the middleware, which will make available to you some helpers in your route and in your template (via locals):

```
// app.js
app.use( shrinkr.middleware );

// routes/index.js
exports.showOrListUsers = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log( "Route: " + req.route.name ); // ta-da, made available by Shrinkroute

  req.buildUrl( "users", { name: "foo" } );
  // or, if you want the full url with the scheme and host...
  req.buildFullUrl( "users", { name: "foo" } );
};
```

And maybe you want to use them in your templates as well?

```
// templates/index.jade
a( href=url( "users", { name: "foo" } ) ) Foo profile
a( href=fullUrl( "users", { name: "foo" } ) ) Foo profile
```

This method has the advantage that you don't get direct access to route setters inside a route.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of Shrinkroute.

Comment: +1 for 'Using the middleware', I should have read the docs better :)

Comment: shrinkroute middleware doesn't work. I get: TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'buildUrl'

Comment: @VladVinnikov [there are tests](https://github.com/gustavohenke/shrinkroute/blob/master/test/index.js#L279) to ensure things works. If you need further help debugging the problem, [please fill in a bug](https://github.com/gustavohenke/shrinkroute/issues/new).

Comment: @VladVinnikov as of v0.3.1, such problems will no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

you should import it. add following line to the very beginning of your code

```
  var shrinkroute = require('shrinkroute');
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but it didn't help. index.js doesn't see shrinkr variable