# Easiest way to pass variables to routes templates in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I've just made an Node.js app modular by splitting up data models and routes into separate files.

My routes are exported by `express.Router()`. In these routes I would like to import queried values from my app.js to be rendered with the templates.

How would I in the easiest way save things lets say with app.locals or req.variableName?

Since the route using `express.Router()` ties it together with app.js, should I be using `app.params()` and somehow make these values accessible?

Using globals seems like a worse idea as I'm scaling up the app. I'm not sure if best practice would be saving values to the process environment either using `app.locals.valueKey = key.someValue`...

Big thanks in advance to anyone

Comment: you should add module.exports = "what you want to return from that module ( js file) "

Comment: Thank you but that's not quite the answer I was looking for. I've used module.exports for all my data models with MongoDB/Mongoose and routes that use express.Router(). Then require() them in the main app.js. However I have some value keys I want to make available in the routes. I can't seem to refer to my main app.js / the object I've tried to export to the routes.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712712/how-to-pass-variable-from-app-js-to-routes-index-js

Comment: I tried using app.set('infoNeeded', infoNeeded); in app.js and then in the route var info = req.app.get('infoNeeded'); without success. I'm not sure if using globals is a good idea storing values in app.locals since they would be available in all the templates considering whats best practice. But my aim to pass information via the templates in the routes so maybe the solution lies there. In that case how do i refer the global's to respective template easily? I would have preferred passing the values in the route: res.render('index.html', { key1, value1, key2, value2 ...etc })

Comment: I would like a clear answer to: 1. find an document with mongoose and map and save 5 other key values, 2. I would like to import these 5 values into my route so I can pass them all to the rendering of the template outputting their contents. Pretty please =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to pass a value to a later middleware:

app.js:

```
// Let's say it's like this in this example

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var user = User.findOne({ email: 'someValue' }, function (err, user) {
        // Returning a document with the keys I'm interested in
        req.user = { key1: value1, key2: value2... }; // add the user to the request object
        next(); // tell express to execute the next middleware
    });
});

// Here I include the route
require('./routes/public.js')(app); // I would recommend passing in the app object
```

/routes/public.js:

```
module.export = function(app) {
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Serving Home Page (where I want to pass in the values)
        router.get('/', function (req, res) {
            // Passing in the values for Swig to render
            var user = req.user; // this is the object you set in the earlier middleware (in app.js)
            res.render('index.html', { pagename: user.key2, ... });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @forrert. I think I'm closer to an answer now.  The core of my problem is that I don't want to do unnecessary queries over again in my included routes when I can lets say store all queried keys in an object and import it.

Comment: Unless you need to execute the query in app.js ( Contents.findOne({ url: siteRequest },...) ) only once in the lifetime of your app (e.g. at the start of the application), I'd still recommend to add the keys & values to the req object for use in a later middleware. I'd also recommend going over the middleware guide on the express.js website: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: Thank you for the link about middleware's in general. Yes I need to execute the query just once in app.js since I need the first value and later its related values in the routes without making another query.

Comment: After reading up through your link in the documentation I think that storing things in the request object is a good suggestion. My alternative could be storing the values in the app object like so: app.set('contents', siteContents); and in route: exports.getContent = function (req, res) { var importedContents = req.app.get('contents'); router.get('/'... }

Comment: Why do you recommend passing in the entire app object? I'm trying to figure out how to pass a single value.

Comment: @tim.rohrer this is just to be able to build the routes in separate modules/files. The key of this answer is to add values to the request object from earlier middlewares to have them available for reading in later middlewares.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to go "back to basics" with modules. I suspect I've been thinking all sorts of wrong with them.