# How to pass value from one route to another in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple route that makes a POST request and returns an object with a number of values. I want to use one of the returned values in another (different) route for different logic. Is there a way to pass such data from one route to another?

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

    // call some function that returns an object for use in another route eg:
    myFunction()
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
});

router.post('/verify', (req, res, next) => {

    // use the data returned from the register route for verification logic 

});
```

Comment: Why you need 2 routes?? In 1st route itself you can do all those stuff. If you need it in 2nd route while calling that route pass the result of 1st route is body params and use it

Comment: I have to different end points. One for registration and one for verification hence the need for different routes. This is just a simplest way of explaining the problem I am facing but the logic of the app is way bigger and I am certain I can not do it in one route

Comment: I think it's not a good idea, But if you have to do it, than you can call your another route with `Axios`. The best practive is you create someting like this. `Route A` have a `UseCaseA` and than `Route B` have a `UseCaseB`. So you only need to using it, I mean `Route B` can use `UseCaseA` and `Route A` can use `UseCaseB`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variable from app.js to routes/index.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712712/how-to-pass-variable-from-app-js-to-routes-index-js)

Comment: http is a stateless protocol. There's no obvious connection between a user's request to */register* and another to */verify*. The best way is to pass the data back to the user which in turn will send it back to the next endpoint.

Comment: @marzelin I agree and understand your point, however in my case the information is sensitive and would not be secure to send it to the user

Comment: then use  `express-session` or store the data in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npm package **connect-flash** for passing data between routes

```
var express = require('express');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();
app.use(flash());

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  // Set a flash message by passing the key, followed by the value, to req.flash().
  req.flash('username', 'Gaurav Gupta')
  res.redirect('/profile');
});

app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
  // Get an array of flash messages by passing the key to req.flash()
  let message = req.flash('username')
  res.render('index', { message: message }); // or {message} only es6 feature
});
```

Or alternatively you can use middlewares on the routes

i.e

```
router.post('/register', middleware(), (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

//define middleware

```
function middleware(){
  return function(req, res, next){
    ...perform actions
    next()
  }
}
```

//reuse middleware in route

```
router.post('/verify', middleware(), (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try express-session to store the value in the session then read it from session variable.
or
you can create an encrypted token and send it to the user as register response, then in verify the route take the token and decrypt it.